# "You've Exceeded Your Question Limit" Comes Up Unexpectedly

Tags: support, bug, asking-questions

**Now, I understand that nobody here understands the algorithm as of how are timed question bans issued ("You've reached your question limit"), however, whatever the algorithm is, this doesn't make sense.**

About 7 days before I found out that I had a four-day question ban. During the period my questions got one downvote and 4 upvotes. However, once the four-day period ended and I posted a new question, a new 7-day ban was issued. The new question did not receive any views or votes then.

- Does one downvote outweigh 4 upvotes **and** make the question ban longer?
- Also, I would want to know if upvotes during the question ban time span can lift the question ban, or do we have to wait for the ban to expire?

People from Code Golf Stack Exchange holds the suspicion that:

> the limit follows you across stacks

(https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61263868#61263868)

as I:

> posted 7 near identical questions simultaneously

However, I pointed out this doesn't make sense because:

> none of my other stacks have a question ban currently
>
> not code golf
>
> not code golf meta
>
> not even puzzle stack exchange meta

**I seek help.**

Comment: Do you have any [deleted questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current)?

Comment: Only one: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116197/solve-this-to-solve-that, Should I undelete that?

Comment: Here is [the FAQ for rate-limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/241919). Looking at the overall score of all of your questions on Puzzling.SE, which is -5 as of current writing (possibly less if the deleted question is also negative), looks like this is in effect: "*Users limited from asking questions for 1 – 7 days [based on the performance of their previous questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)*".

Comment: Well, why do I get banned longer after an improvement? Unless the 1-7 days is randomly chosen which I think and hope isn't the case.

Comment: Rate-limiting tends to double each time. Also, the improvement was probably too late considering that the overall score is still -5. The system always counts the overall history, not only the recent one.

Comment: OK now I got this, but I think the ban should wait a bit? Banning me once the ban was lifted and I just posted a question? argh...

Comment: Also, why does the ban come after my question post, does question posts of score 0 decrease the score?

Comment: The "ban" is actually a *rate-limit* for one post every X days so long as your question record runs foul of the algorithm. Once you post, that uses up the amount of questions per X days - it hits the limit - so you can't post another.

Comment: OK i hate 15 character limit